# Resolving names on local WiFi using local DNS

Tags: android, dns, lan, names

Why can't Android resolve the name of a computer on my LAN using the router DNS, like my PC does? How can I get around this? I do not want to have to assign static addresses to equipment in order for Android devices to find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used JCIFS NbtAddress addr = NbtAddress.getByName()

Comment: NbtAddress.getByName("my-computer-domain-name"); ?? Didn't work, says `Unknown host exception`